# Реализовать ASSUME на nasm

Tags: ассемблер

Мне нужно некоторый код из masm переделать под nasm и я встретил

```
ASSUME  ES:CODE
```

Как это правильно реализовать на nasm, я написал такой код

```
xor AX,AX
mov es, ax
```

это правильно или нет? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `push cs --> pop es`